# Using Manipulate to show how Fourier transform varies

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I have done the piecewise Fourier transform and now I am stuck with trying to get the final plot (on final picture) to make a manipulable plot.

I am new to Mathematica, hence I am using the trial version. The question has been done and I am not sure if answer is correct. I just need to know how to manipulate a double plotted wave of the step wave and the Fourier one with respect to `n`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Regards, Ben.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! Please do not post screenshots of your code. Instead, post the code in proper *Mathematica* syntax, properly formatted in code blocks. Edit our post by clicking the grey edit button at the bottom of your post and click the grey question mark on the right side of the editing toolbar for formatting help.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to use `Piecewise` rather than `While`. Not a big deal but `Piecewise` is specifically designed for this type of problem. I am also going to use less than or equal so that there are no gaps (again, probably no affect for this problem).

```
f[t_] := Piecewise[{{-2, -π < t < -π/2}, {0, -π/2 <= t < 0},
          { 3, 0 <= t < π}}]
```

Now plot it and save the plot

```
plot1 = Plot[f[t], {t, -π, π}, Exclusions -> None, 
  Ticks -> {{-π, -π/2, 0, π/2, π}, {-2, 3}}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-2.5, 3.5}}, PlotStyle -> Black]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For the second plot the input function will be

```
FourierTrigSeries[f[t], t, n]
```

where `n` is the integer selected in `Manipulate`. However one needs to wrap this expression in `Evaluate` before feeding it to plot.

Below is an example with `n` = 3.

```
Plot[Evaluate[FourierTrigSeries[f[t], t, 3]], {t, -π, π}, 
 Ticks -> {{-π, -(π/2), 0, π/2, π}, {-2, 3}}, 
 PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Put this in a `Manipulate` where we ask for the number `n` to be an odd integer from 1 to 21. Use `Show` to display the two plots together.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  plot1,
  Plot[Evaluate[FourierTrigSeries[f[t], t, n]], {t, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
   Ticks -> {{-\[Pi], -(\[Pi]/2), 0, \[Pi]/2, \[Pi]}, {-2, 3}}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red]
  ],
 {{n, 3}, 1, 21, 2}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above was for `n=3`. The figure below is for `n=7`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That's great thank you! This is good for visualizing the convergence, very helpful.